# Cannot push commit to gitosis running on virtualbox

Tags: git, gitosis

After some work, I was able to install Gitosis on Ubuntu Server 11.04 on my local system using VirtualBox.  I set up port forwarding so that port 2222 on my local machine matches up with port 22 on the virtual server, and I've been able to access the server using putty as well as standard ssh.

I was able to install and configure gitosis, and was even able to "git clone gitosis-init" and access that directory.  I did have to use a standard ssh command versus the standard git clone nomenclature

i.e. my git command was:

```
git clone ssh://gitosis@localhost:2222/~/repositories/gitosis-admin.git
```

And everything worked fine.  I basically copied over the group creation section for gitosis-admin and changed the writable field to the project's name:

```
[group test]
members = rsa_key
writable = test_proj
```

and pushed that to the server.  Everything seems great.

I then created the local directory, initialized it with git init, created a file and added it with "git add ."  I generated a commit statement as well as a remote add statement similar to the clone one above, and then tried to push it:

```
git remote add origin ssh://gitosis@localhost:2222/~/repositories/test_proj.git
git push --all
```

Yet when I push, I receive a

```
    fatal:  the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have no idea what is causing this.  My pub/private keys seem to be working, and even using git push -v --all for some insight doesn't give my anything.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by re-installing the git repository on the virtualbox.  Issue had to do with a network setting not matching up; once I reinstalled and set he proper port, all seems to work.